# Create dictionary comprehension using multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am a newbie in python.
I have 3 lists (price_list/address_list/link_list), I am trying to combine them in one dictionary with this structure:

```
{
    {
        "price":price,
        "address":address,
        "link":link,
    },
    {
        "price":price,
        "address":address,
        "link":link,
    }
}
```

I am able to create the list  with nested dictionaries but not dictionary with nested dictionary

```
my_dict = [{'price': price, 'address': address, 'link': link} for price, address, link in zip(price_list, address_list, link_list)]
```

What would be the equivalent please?

Comment: Your example shows a "set of dictionaries", not a "dictionary of dictionaries". A set of dictionaries is not possible in python. What would the keys of your dictionary of dictionaries be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike List, Dictionary is like a JSON object, i.e. always has a key-value pair. So you must specify a key, like this:

```
myDict = {
  "dict1":{                                 // Key
            "price":price,                  // Values
            "address":address,
            "link":link,
          },
  "dict2":{                                 // Key
            "price":price,                  // Values
            "address":address,
            "link":link,
          }
}
```

Assuming all three lists you have are of the same length, you can do this to get a nested dictionary:

```
myDict = {}
for i in range(len(price_list)):            // You can use any other list instead.
  myDict[i] = {                             // Or whatever key suites you.
    "price": price_list[i]
    "address": addess_list[i]
    "link": link_list[i]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is essentially a data structure that maps certain values to a collection of keys. Your inner dictionary seems to be fine. You have defined a key and a value. However, in your outer dictionary, you seem to be only having list of values (the inner dicts) and no key to associate them with.

For instance, I have added 'key1' and 'key2' to demonstrate that your outer dictionary needs to have keys defined.

```js
{
    "key1": {
        "price":price,
        "address":address,
        "link":link,
    },
    "key2": {
        "price":price,
        "address":address,
        "link":link,
    }
}
```

So what you're asking is not exactly possible.

However, if you manage to find some keys for your outer dictionary, then you can iterate over the list of dicts that you already have and then assign the elements of the list against some key in the outer dict.

Something like this should work if you're looking for a one-liner:

```py
my_dict = {i: j for i,j in zip(range(len(price_list)), [{'price': price, 'address': address, 'link': link} for price, address, link in zip(price_list, address_list, link_list)])}
```

It would return:

```js
{
      0: {'price': price1, 'address': 'addr1', 'link': 'link1'}, 
      1: {'price': price2, 'address': 'addr2', 'link': 'link2'}, 
      2: {'price': price3, 'address': 'addr3', 'link': 'link3'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks got it with the examples

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a Dictionary with nested Dictionaries like you created one with the list.
This is due to the fact that every element in a dictionary must have a key.
If you want to create a nested dictionary then the outermost dictionary (containing dictionaries) must have keys for every dictionary.

```
{
1 :{
    "price":price,
    "address":address,
    "link":link,
},
2 :{
    "price":price,
    "address":address,
    "link":link,
}
```

}

Something like this where 1, 2 are keys.

to do this simply initialize a variable with 1
then after adding values increment the variable

for eg

```
in loop()
    i = 1
    dic  = {}
    dic[i] = "whatever"
    i += 1
```